# Double click on jar file dosen't work (turn .jar to .exe)

Tags: cmd.exe, java, jdk, jre, jar

I am trying to turn my java program into an .exe.

With the help of IntelliJ IDEA I created a .jar file and I'm able to run it from my os cmd with java -jar and it works great.

When I double click the .jar file nothing happens.
I'm using jdk 17 and jre 8.

I also tried to make an .exe file from the .jar using launch4j but when I'm trying to run the .exe file I'm getting:
"A java exception has occurred"
There are no more error details.

I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks a lot for the help, I'm a bit new to this topic, so far I've written a lot codes before but I haven't converted them to a running .exe file
Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I cannot so I will go ahead and delete my original comment. I mean technically I could but my suggestion is just based suspicion based on my extensive experience with similar situations

Comment: Try [JAR to EXE Online Converter](https://genuinecoder.com/online-converter/jar-to-exe/).

Comment: See if you can generate the exe with console (on Windows this means using java.exe rather than javaw.exe) so you can see exception stack trace.  It would be helpful if you asked once only, rather than [duplicate this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235996/turn-a-java-jar-file-to-an-exe). See the comments made in stackoverflow. I would recommend `jpackage` for building executables as you can package up multiple applications with a single installer.

Comment: Windows double click action on a jar is dependent the file association. Try checking the "Opens with" application used by right mouse -> Properties. Type "blah.jar" in CMD to see if that reports anything to the cmd window - that should attempt same launch as double click.

Comment: @DuncG I'v tried to open my jar file with jre and jdk.
Open with jdk/bin/javaw do nothing
Open with jdk/bin/java open cmd for 1 sec and close it automatically
same for open with jre/bin/java

Comment: @Jhon What you said does not make sense - using java from cmd should not be opening a new window unless your own app does. In which case you should have stack trace - unless you have `catch` and no code to handle / print exception. I suggest you edit one of your questions with exact details of what you have typed and the messages you get back.

Comment: @DuncG its not opens a new window, when I'm writing java -jar myapp in my cmd the app runs in the same cmd i'v opened and all works great, the problem is when I double click my jar file. nothing happens there

Comment: @Jhon As I said, launch the jar from the cmd as that should be same action as double click.

Comment: If it works in CMD, then just make a very short batch script with that CMD line. Double-click the .bat file to run the Java app. Using a batch file also allows for editing arguments such as memory allocation.